# using awk command to manipulate columns

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have about 175 tab delimited `txt` files in a directory. I am interested in the first column, I want to remove all repeated items from the first column of each file, and then print them as columns in a new `txt` file.

```
#this removes all duplicates in column 1 of myFile.txt
awk '!x[$1]++' myFile.txt 

#this copies all coulmn 1 from every file and paste them as columns in a new file 

#!/bin/bash
OUT=AllColumns.tsv
touch $OUT

for file in *.txt
do
   paste $OUT <(awk -F\\t '{print $1}' $file) > $OUT.tmp
   mv $OUT.tmp $OUT
done
```

My Question, How can i combine these two commands so that it prints out column 1 (without duplicate items) from every file into a new file as columns?

Comment: do you mean this? `awk '{a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x}' *.txt`

Comment: Show a few lines from a few input files and what the output should be. I'm not sure what you mean by ".. into a new file as columns". Do you mean there should be one output file with multiple columns, each column corresponding to column 1 of one of the input files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print in a new file (1 per original txt), only first occurrence of first column by file (original file name + `.filtered.txt`)

```
awk '!( $1 in F){F[$1]++; print $1 > FILENAME ".filtered.txt" }' *.txt
```

if uniq PER file is needed (thanks to @karakfa for this remark)

```
awk '!( $1","FILENAME in F){F[$1","FILENAME]++; print $1 > FILENAME ".filtered.txt" }' *.txt
```

Comment: this will print unique items in all files, not unique per file.  May or may not be what the OP is asking.